# Check if multiple strings are present in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, text

I am trying to determine if two variables are found in the `dataframe`

```
table:
Code    index
600.SI  4th Q 2015
500.SI  Full Year
ggr.SI  1st Q 2016

# If variable_code and variable_date is not found in table, print not found
if table['Code'].str.contains(variable_code).any() & table['index'].str.contains(variable_date).any():
    print('found')
else:
    print('not found')
```

However, it always return me `found`.

I think my `if` statement is structured incorrectly to do a `bool` comparison for two items.

How can this be solved?

**Update**

Normally, `variable_code` will be found in `table`. if `variable_code` is found in `table`, check if `variable_date` is present too.

What I am trying to achieve is, If both of these conditions are not present, print `not found`.

Comment: Apologies, I was away so could not test the solution / respond. Thank you very much for helping with the answer, i'll give them a shot shortly! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `str.contains`, `regex=True` by default, so if you're not careful, you won't be matching the right things. If you want to check for equality rather than containment, use the `==` operator, like this:

```
if not table[(table['Code'] == variable_code) 
             & (table['index'] == variable_date)].empty: # https://stackoverflow.com/a/45780191/4909087
    print('Found')
else:
    print('Not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `&` with `and`. `&` is Bitwise AND operator.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly Danil. I have tried that, but it still does not work. It still prints `found`. Just to add, `variable_code` will normally be found in the `table`, but if `variable_code` is found, `and` `variable_date` is not found, then print `not found`. That is what I am trying to achieve