# Pandaic way to check whether a dataframe has any rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe `df`, I'd apply some condition `df[condition]` and retrieve a subset. I just want to check if there are any rows in the subset - this would tell me the condition is a valid one.

```
In [551]: df
Out[551]: 
   Col1
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
5     3
6     1
7     2
8     3
```

What I want to check is something like this:

```
if df[condition] has rows:
    do something
```

What is the best way to check whether a filtered dataframe has rows? Here's some methods that don't work:

1. `if df[df.Col1 == 1]:` Gives `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous.`
2. `if df[df.Col1 == 1].any():` Also gives `ValueError`

I suppose I can test the `len`. Are there other ways?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `df.empty`:

```
df_conditional = df.loc[df['column_name'] == some_value]
if not df_conditional.empty:
    ... # process dataframe results
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828822/how-to-check-whether-a-pandas-dataframe-is-empty suggests that using `len` is faster .Worth to check out